# How to add common arguments to argparse subcommands?

Tags: python, python-2.7, argparse

When using argparse, some subcommands need the same options and I'm using `parents` to avoid repeatedly defining them in every sub-command.

script filename:  `testarg.py`

```
import argparse                                                                  

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)                                 
parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', default='192.168.122.1')                     
parser.add_argument('-P', '--port', default='12345')                             
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()                                             

# subcommand a                                                                   
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', parents=[parser])                          
parser_a.add_argument('-D', '--daemon', action='store_true')                     

parser_a.add_argument('-L', '--log', default='/tmp/test.log')                    

# subcommand b                                                                   
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', parents=[parser])                          
parser_b.add_argument('-D', '--daemon', action='store_true')                     

# subcommand c                                                                   
parser_c = subparsers.add_parser('c', parents=[parser])                          
args = parser.parse_args()                                                       

print args
```

But when I run command:

```
>>>./testarg.py a
usage: testarg.py a [-h] [-H HOST] [-P PORT] [-D] [-L LOG] {a,b,c} ...
testarg.py a: error: too few arguments
```

expecting output:

```
>>>./testarg.py a
Namespace(daemon=False, host='192.168.122.1', log='/tmp/test.log', port='12345')

>>>./testarg.py b -H 127.0.0.1 -P 11111
Namespace(daemon=False, host='127.0.0.1', port='11111')

>>>./testarg.py c
Namespace(host='192.168.122.1', port='12345')

also, 

>>>./testarg.py c -H 127.0.0.1 -P 12222
Namespace(host='127.0.0.1', port='12222')
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Could you please explain what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: @Alik,  answer updated. I want to run some sub-commands with the same option (`-H`, `-P`), but I don't want to add them in every sub-commands.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Make a separate parent parser and pass it to subparsers

```
import argparse                                                                  

parent_parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)                                 
parent_parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', default='192.168.122.1')                     
parent_parser.add_argument('-P', '--port', default='12345')                             

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False) 
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()                                             

# subcommand a                                                                   
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a', parents = [parent_parser])                          
parser_a.add_argument('-D', '--daemon', action='store_true')                     

parser_a.add_argument('-L', '--log', default='/tmp/test.log')                    

# subcommand b                                                                   
parser_b = subparsers.add_parser('b', parents = [parent_parser])                          
parser_b.add_argument('-D', '--daemon', action='store_true')                     

# subcommand c                                                                   
parser_c = subparsers.add_parser('c', parents = [parent_parser])                          
args = parser.parse_args()                                                       

print args
```

This gives desired result

```
$ python arg.py a
Namespace(daemon=False, host='192.168.122.1', log='/tmp/test.log', port='12345')
$ python arg.py b -H 127.0.0.1 -P 11111
Namespace(daemon=False, host='127.0.0.1', port='11111')
$ python arg.py c
Namespace(host='192.168.122.1', port='12345')
```

Comment: thanks, it works. I read official argparse doc but did not figure out the method, how do you know this?  any doc?

Comment: The docs have  a `parents` section, and a `subparsers` section, which you've read.  You are putting those together in an unexpected way.  It's hard to anticipate all applications.

Comment: The `add_help` here `parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(add_help=False)` is not needed.

Comment: I needed `add_help=False` for the `parent_parser`, but not for `parser`. Without this on the parent parser it throws an error. Setting `add_help=False` on `parent_parser` does not prevent the parent parser options from being listed in --help for `parser`.

Comment: This is a nice solution! BEWARE however: a bug currently exists in CPython that may silently skip options provided before subcommands: https://github.com/python/cpython/pull/30146

Answer (score 9):

When you use `parser` itself as a `parents` of the subparsers, you recursively add `subparsers` to each subparser.  The `add_subparsers` command actually defines a positional argument, one that gets choices, `{'a','b','c'}`.  It ends up expecting `prog.py a a a ...`, each subparser expects another subparser command etc.

I've never seen anyone try this kind of definition, and it took a bit of thinking to realize what was happening.

`@Alik's` approach is a correct one.  Define the parent parser separately, and don't use it directly.  It is just a source for those `-H` and `-P` Actions that you want added to each subparser.  That's all you want to add to the subparsers.

Another approach is to simply define `-H` and `-P` in the main parser.

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('-H', '--host', default='192.168.122.1')
parser.add_argument('-P', '--port', default='12345')
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()

# subcommand a
parser_a = subparsers.add_parser('a')
parser_a.add_argument('-D', '--daemon', action='store_true')
....
```

It will function in the same way, except that `-H` and `-P` will have to be specified before the subparser command.

```
0015:~/mypy$ python stack33645859.py -H 127.0.0.1 -P 1111 b
Namespace(daemon=False, host='127.0.0.1', port='1111')
```

They still appear in the namespace in the same way, it's just that order in the commandline is different.  `help` will also be different.

A third option is to add the common arguments programmatically, with a loop or function.  A crude example is:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
subparsers = parser.add_subparsers()
splist = []
for cmd in ['a','b','c']:
    p = subparsers.add_parser(cmd)
    p.add_argument('-H', '--host', default='192.168.122.1')
    p.add_argument('-P', '--port', default='12345')
    splist.append(p)
splist[0].add_argument('-D', '--daemon', action='store_true')
```

Functionally it will be similar to `@Alik's` approach, with a subtle difference.  With the `parent`, only one pair of `H` and `P` Action objects is created.  References are added to each subparser.

With mine, each subparser gets its own `H` and `P` Action object.  Each subparser could define different `defaults` for those arguments.  I remember this being an issue in one other SO question.

Coding work is similar in all cases.

Comment: Thanks for your great explanation. many thanks. Actually, I tried both methods you suggested. I ask the questions because  I think the -P and -H are a part of every sub-commands but not the root parser, the  -H and -P have to  specified before sub-command is not what i want. do you have any suggestion about how to do sub-commands with common options pythonic?

Comment: My last suggestion looks quite pythonic to me.